# How to obtain the goal function of DMRG by Lagrange multiplier method?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, tensor-network, optimization

The goal of DMRG is to minimize the expectation value of energy, which can be written as

$$ \frac{d}{d |\psi \rangle} \frac{\langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi \rangle}{\langle \psi | \psi \rangle} = 0. \tag{1}$$

In [*The density-matrix renormalization group in the age of matrix product states*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1008.3477) by Ulrich Schollwoeck it's written that this formula can be rewritten with the use of Lagrange multiplier method, giving us

$$ \frac{d}{d |\psi \rangle} (\langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi \rangle - \lambda \langle \psi | \psi \rangle) = 0. \tag{2}$$

I'm not quite sure how to obtain (2) from (1). If we split (1) into two parts, the first being the function to be optimized

$$ f(\hat{H}, |\psi \rangle) = \langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi \rangle, $$

and the second being the equality constraint (ensuring proper normalization of the state)

$$ g(|\psi \rangle ) = \langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1, $$

which in turn can be restated as $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle - 1 = 0$, we can write the Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}$ as

$$ \mathcal{L}(\hat{H}, | \psi \rangle, \lambda) = f(\hat{H}, |\psi \rangle) - \lambda g(|\psi \rangle ) \\ = \langle \psi | \hat{H} | \psi \rangle - \lambda \langle \psi | \psi \rangle - \lambda. \tag{3} $$

**My question is, what happens to the rightmost $\lambda$?** My guess was, that it will just shift the final energy obtained, or it will simply vanish when taking the derivative over $| \psi \rangle$, so we can omit it. On the other hand, formula (3) without the last $\lambda$ would correspond to a situation, in which $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 0$, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well, the *derivative* of (3) has to be vanish, right? The constant will then disappear, and you get (2).

Comment: I thought so, but then how does it differ from the situation, in which $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 0$?

Comment: I don't see your point. You have $\lambda(\langle\psi|\psi\rangle-1)$, so why would $\lambda$ be zero? Also, you are *not* setting $\lambda$ to zero - you are taking the derivative.

Comment: I mean, $\frac{d}{d|\psi \rangle} (\lambda(\langle \psi | \psi \rangle - 1))$ (corresponding to the constraint with $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 1$) is the same as  $\frac{d}{d|\psi \rangle}  (\lambda\langle \psi | \psi \rangle)$ (corresponding to the constraint with $\langle \psi | \psi \rangle = 0$), so how does DMRG "know" that the state must be normalized?

Comment: You have an additional equation $0 = \frac{d \mathcal{L}}{d\lambda} = \langle \psi | \psi\rangle -1$

Comment: Ok, that settles this :) And this additional equation is indirectly enforced while running the Lanczos algorithm, when solving the eigenvalue problem?

Comment: In DMRG you solve problem (1) (or rather, you find its minimum by solving an eigenvalue equation). Whether you think of this in terms of lagrange multipliers or not is up to you. I don't see why you would want to reformulate it like that.